# How to check a cell text is strikethrough or not in .xlsx file using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ms-office

I need to check the text format of a cell in **.xlsx** file (Microsoft Excel file) is **strike through** or not using ***Apache POI*** libraries.

Look following Image

[Please Check this image !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beg4M.png)

I need to check whether B3 Cell text is **strike through** or not.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What did you try? What do you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do this, code as follow

```
//Using workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("abc.xlsx")));
//Getting first sheet
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
//Checking A1 cell that strikethrough or not
boolean strikeOutStatus=sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFont().getStrikeout();
System.out.println(strikeOutStatus);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

1. Get the `XSSFRichTextString` from the cell using [`XSSFCell#getRichStringCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getRichStringCellValue())
2. Get the `XSSFFont` at a specific position using [`XSSFRichTextString#getFontAtIndex(int index)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html#getFontAtIndex(int))
3. Check the font using [`XSSFFont#getStrikeout()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getStrikeout())

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you get a reference to it but there's [HSSFont.getStrikeout()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFont.html#getStrikeout%28%29) and [XSSFFont.getStrikeout()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getStrikeout%28%29)