# Apache POI for Java: Finding strikeout text in cell value

Tags: java, excel, apache, fonts, apache-poi

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is open a .xlsx file and remove all instances of text that is formatted (styled?) with <strike>strikeout</strike>. This seemed really easy at first: Check the number of formatting runs in a cell with CellType String, check the font of each character between the runs, so on and so forth. 
I created an .xlsx with test cases, stuff like:

<strike>this</strike> is a test

<strike>this is</strike> a test

this is <strike>a test</strike>

<strike>this is a test</strike>

The first three tests have formatting runs at the cell value level. The last test had **zero** formatting runs at the cell value level, but XSSFFont.getStrikeout() is **true** when checked against the cell's CellStyle.getFont(). XSSFFont.getStrikeout() is  **false** when checked against the CellStyle.getFont() of the first three tests (strikeout existed only within the XSSFRichTextString)
Here's what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("test.xlsx");
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Iterator<Row> rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
    while(rowIter.hasNext()) {
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIter = row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIter.hasNext()) {
            XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
            XSSFCellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
            XSSFFont font = style.getFont();
            if(font.getStrikeout()){
                System.out.println("CellStyle/font has strikeout, but...");
            }
            XSSFRichTextString richStr = (XSSFRichTextString) cell.getRichStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("This ends up being 0, meaning there's no strikeout applied to the RichTextString " + richStr.numFormattingRuns());
        }
    }
    workbook.close();
}
```

I tried this in a different workbook (the one I'm trying to eliminate strikeout text in), which has cell contents like the first three tests (strikeout scattered throughout different substrings) - turns out they all have CellStyle.getFont().getStrikeout() being **true**, whereas I would expect them it to be **false** so this throws the proverbial wrench in my cogs. 
 Please help, I don't like being beaten by Excel :(

Comment: Close - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037299/how-to-check-a-cell-text-is-strikethrough-or-not-in-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi) suggests a few changes.

Comment: Loop over all the rich text strings checking those?

Comment: That's the thing, I've checked those and they don't offer any more information than what I already know. The **cell** font has the strikeout, not the string font, even though the string has regular font and strikeout, so none of the applicable XSSFRichTextString methods apply

Comment: In Excel there are two possibilities: **Either** the whole cell's style is **not** formatted strike out but maybe single run parts in the rich-text content **are** formatted strike out **or** the whole cell's style **is** formatted strike out but maybe single run parts in the rich-text content are **not** formatted strike out. So first determine how the whole cell's style is formatted but then, if there are formatted run parts, also check formatting of those run parts.

Comment: Thanks for the info Axel - I'll check it out when I get a chance and update with what I found